# Silverlight 5 Get Usercontrol's handle

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, user-controls, pinvoke

I'm trying to make a PInvoke call to register any USB device connection notification.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hwnd, DeviceBroadcastInterface oInterface, uint nFlags);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public class DeviceBroadcastInterface
{
    public int Size;
    public int DeviceType;
    public int Reserved;
    public Guid ClassGuid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string Name;
}
```

A handle to the window, normally obtained from OnHandleCreated in Winforms application is required to make such PInvoke calls. Is there a way of obtaining a handle of the usercontrol in silverlight 5?

Comment: What made you decide to use `Pack=1`? Are you sure that is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight, unlike WPF, does not expose window handles. However, you can, if you try hard enough, find the handle to your window. This [article](http://trelford.com/blog/post/AgSpackle.aspx) describes the method. Essentially you call the `FindWindow` function to get hold of the window handle.

And remember that you won't get a handle for your user control because only top level windows have handles under Silverlight. Silverlight controls are not windowed.

As an aside, are you quite sure that your struct is packed? That would be quite unusual.

Comment: That's a snippet of code obtained from a working library, so I'm assuming yes to your last question.

Comment: That's not evidence enough. It might work by chance. Perhaps packed and aligned happen to have the same layout for this struct. Unless the native code explicitly packs you should pack.

Comment: So far as I can tell from `dbt.h`, the struct is not packed. It so happens that there is no padding, so you cannot tell the difference. I recommend that you remove `Pack=1`.